# mac bash terminal replaces one "\" with three "\\\" when pressing tab on folder with spaces on name

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am trying to check my bash_profile, bashrc, and /etc/profile, and i dont have ~/.inputrc, so I am going crazy trying to figure out what I did that every time I use tilde "~" when I want to auto complete the name of a directory, it replaces any folder with a space which on mac it shows as `"~/Sample/Folder\ Space/"` and if I press tab on this folder or after Sample, it will turn that into `"~/Sample/Folder\\\ Space/"` and I get an error that the directory doesnt exist which is true.. I forgot what I pressed that is doing this.. ughhhh

Comment: Just wanted to update this that I went to another machine with same OS and same bash version, etc, no inputrc file, all files in /etc/ the same, such as rc.common, bashrc , bashrc_Apple_terminal, shopt variables, i think the set was different, bash-auto-completion was the same, and when I type in terminal ~/Sample/Folder\ Space\ it basically adds backslashes to the path at the spaces section turning it into ~/Sample/Folder\\\ Space\ 
example:

using terminal:
```
i type the following
user$ ~/Folder

then i press tab twice or more
user$ ~/Folder --becomes-- user$ ~/Folder\\\ Name/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just create a new `~/.inputrc` restart the terminal window?
You can put the below entries in your new `~/.inputrc`

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
```

**Steps:**

1. Type `nano ~/.inputrc` from your terminal Paste the following on
   separate lines

   ```
   set completion-ignore-case on
   set show-all-if-ambiguous on
   TAB: menu-complete
   ```
2. Hit `Control+O` to save changes to `~/.inputrc` followed by
   `control+X` to quit.
3. Open a new Terminal window or tab, or type "login" to open a new session with the rules in effect.
4. Type and hit the `tab` key.

Comment: So I had already done this and it worked, but I was looking for a reason as to why all of a sudden it started happening if I never had an inputrc file.. I am actually an advanced user of mac and linux but was sort of looking more into what changed in other parts of the terminal or system control since like I said i never had an inputrc in my ~ home and it happened after some brew installations or rebuilding and compiling nano for this system... but I will mark your answer as acceptable in case others experience the same issue.